# how to make resposive dialog of primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want make responsive modal, help me.

```
<p:dialog id="idModal" widgetVar="modalWV" modal="true" width="600" header="Titulo Modal">

   <h:panelGrid id="panelPermisoGuardar" columns="2" cellpadding="10" width="100%"
      //campos
   </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

This is how it looks when I see it on a responsive screen

[Non-responsive Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ca6.png)

Comment: English please, or use https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I already translated it although I had already solved it thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

First create the Dialog with a panel inside for the fields.

```
 <p:dialog id="modal" widgetVar="modalWV" modal="true" styleClass="modalResponsivo" header="Titulo Modal">

   <h:panelGrid id="idPanel" columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="ui-g-12 ui-md-2,ui-g-12 ui-md-10" layout="grid">

   </h:panelGrid>

</p:dialog>
```

Then add the css rule for the 'modalResponsivo' class

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px ) {
  .modalResponsivo { width: 90% !important;} }

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px ) {
  .modalResponsivo { width: 30% !important; }
}
```

This looks like a full screen [Imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4cl.png)

And that's how it looks a responsive screen [Imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkWmt.png)

Comment: Ok, I did not know